# Does BigQuery Has an api to return a Checksum for a exported table

Tags: google-bigquery, checksum

I'm looking out if there exist a way we can get the checksum of the file (or table) that can be export from google bigquery.

Example assuming that I exported(or downloaded) a file called 
`daily-record-2018-07-10` from bigquery, is there a way bigquery can provide us with some `checksum` (like `sha1`, `md5` etc) so that we can precompute those checksum on our end before we start processing those files

The reason to do so is to be sure that we aren't losing any information when are downloading(or exporting) the table. We do lose some information over the network then we can precompute the checksum and attempt again to export the table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like the question may be about how to checksum a *file*, and I'm sure there are plenty of resources about that, but if you want to checksum a table that is stored in BigQuery, you can use a query of this form:

```
SELECT BIT_XOR(FARM_FINGERPRINT(TO_JSON_STRING(t)))
FROM MyTable AS t
```

This converts each row to a string representation, hashes, and then XORs the results to generate a checksum across the table. You can also use this on external tables (e.g. files on Cloud Storage or Drive).

Comment: that would to as well but a just a question but to_json_string is not a function `Unrecognized function to_json_string`

Comment: You need to use standard SQL in BigQuery.

Comment: Thats great one 1 problem solved One last question though how do I generate a checksum for the table one I have downloaded it(on my linux box). I still need a way to compare the checksum in order to verify that the downloaded data was loseless and authentic

Comment: Check the documentation for `TO_JSON_STRING` and `FARM_FINGERPRINT`. The former has a spec that should be possible to replicate in any programming language, and there is an open source implementation of the FarmHash fingerprint on GitHub that you can probably leverage.